# Deploy/run: local Express web-server and local client-side angular app that sends ajax requests to this local web-server

Tags: angular, express, electron, web-deployment, nwjs

I have:

1. A *node express-based web-server* that should be running only on the user's local machine
2. An *angular client application*, that sends GET Http requests to that local web-server to get data in JSON and display it on the browser

In my dev environment I start these as follows:

1. `npm run dev`  (on the directory of the express web server). It produces: "Express server listening on port 7000" and is ready to receive requests
2. `npm start`  (on the directory of the client application). This launches the client app in the browser. Then I can type, click buttons and get data (from the web-server) displayed.

I want to provide this system to an end user in a convenient way for them:

1. The target environment is Windows. Ideally they should run a single installation (such as from an .msi file).
2. When the installation is complete, they should be able to start the system (both the web-server and the client application) with a single command.
3. The end user is not supposed to know anything about node, npm, .. etc, neither should they know the home directories of the two components -- in fact they may not be even aware that a local express web-server is being used.

What is important is not only a convenient installation, but then to be able to start both system components with a single user command. When the user closes the client application, ideally the express web-server should also be closed.

I played with [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/), but it seems it will not deploy and start the express server that is needed by the electron application. Also read about [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) but haven't seen any example similar to my scenario.

I know that maybe??? I can implement the server-side as one of the electron renderer processes and, instead of HTTP, use inter-process communication (IPC) to communicate with the client-app (another renderer process) involving the main process in this. However, this would require substantial reworking of this already existing system, which would need significant time and is not affordable at present.

Is the deployment and usage scenario (1, 2, 3 above) possible and what are the best tools to use for implementing such deployment and execution scenario?

Could you provide reference(s) to any such implementations? And/or ideally small/complete code examples?

Comment: Is it needed to run local express server?  Keep the server seperate from electron. Dont integrate it together. So your render process can send request to server

Comment: @namila007, Yes, the express server is used only on the local machine. How can I give the user one single installation package, that will install the local Express web-server and the client-side application. And then how can we have a single-command that starts first the Express server and then the client application? What is the best way to do such compact installation and invocation?

Comment: @namila007, The reason for the local Express server is that the system uses a component which cannot run under a browser (puppeteer), and this component provides the data that the client (browser) application displays to the user. It is a requirement to only install locally to individual users and not to have to maintain a remote/central website.

Comment: to up the express server you can run start express by `spawning a child-process`  from your electron app. so user dont need to manage the express. once the server is `ok` app need to continue and work https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: @namila007, Thank you. Do you think puppeteer can run in a renderer child process of Electron (not in the main process)?  Because puppeteer actually needs to be able to do things that cannot be done inside an ordinary browser. For example, it itself starts Chrome for its own use.

Comment: its better to run pupperteer in main process. check this > https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4655#issuecomment-511732866 and  other comments. you will find alot of useful resources

Comment: Thank you @namila007. This is very helpful. If you post an answer with all this information, I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: sure i will add it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Yo can pack both electron app and express server in the production. In developing you need to develop the express app and execute it using [nodejs `child-process` module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Here you can use [`exec` command](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [`spawn` command](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) ( i prefer exec, easy to use). The you can start the express process from you electron `main` process. Wait till the express server setup and then move on with the app.

And for the puppeteer I suggest you to take a look in [this github thread](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4655#issuecomment-511732866) . They are saying to execute puppeteer on the `main process` and communicate the `main` and  `renderer` processes by [electron IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

For building windows installer I think its better to use [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) and generate a [nsis installer](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) with a signed certificate